# using pip3 with 3.7?

Tags: pip, python-3.7

this should be dead simple but ive googled for ages and can't find anything on this. maybe too generic of a search.

I have several vms. centos and ubuntu.

they both always come with python3.6 which has always been fine with me. but i gotta do some devwork on an app written in 3.7. So i installed that in ubuntu using the apt-get install python3.7 which went fine but it seems the modules I install with pip3 work on in python3.6...

pip3 install future

import future

works in 3.6 but not 3.7.

What I do?
-thx

Comment: what's the output of `which pip3`? I guess you only install it for python 3.6. You might try `/path/to/python3.7 -m pip install future` to install it for python 3.7

Comment: you sir, deserve a beer. which pip3 just returns a /user/bin/pip3 which isn't helpful. but python3 -m pip install <package> just straight up worked. i aliased python3 to python3.7 already so the long form you posted is what worked. annoying to have to install all same packages. but will get me what i need. post this as an answer so i can mark it. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`which pip3` points to `/usr/bin/pip3` hence pip3 install only installs it for `python3.6`.
For python3.7 you can use `/path/to/python3.7 -m pip install future` to install it.